# Use SendKeys to send Alt combinations to enter special characters

Tags: vb.net, keypress, sendkeys

I want to send an Alt combination to another window within a on-screen keyboard. 
With combination I mean when you hold down Alt and enter a number or hexadecimal(registry key has to be set for hex) combination:

`ALT down, Add press, 2 press, 5 press, 1 press, ALT up`

I tried

`SendKeys.SendWait("%{ADD}251")` but it's *Alt+Add 2 5 1*

`SendKeys.SendWait("%{ADD}%2%5%1")` but it's *Alt+Add Alt+2 Alt+5 Alt+1*

`SendKeys.SendWait("%({ADD}251)")` but it's *Alt and then the other keys pressed simultaneously*

[Ref to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.80).aspx)

Any suggestions for a solution with SendKeys or other classes?

[Edit]
**Solution:**

Example for CharCode (Element of enum Source): `ʊ = &H28A`

`Dim CharCodeUnicodeStr As String = Hex(CInt([Enum].Parse(GetType(Source), CharStr))).ToString
SendKeys.SendWait("%{ADD}%" & ChrW(Convert.ToInt32(CharCodeUnicodeStr, 16)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%{ADD}%" & ChrW(&H251))
```

This will convert your hexa code into a char. Then if you have control over the other application you can revert this char back to a number...

Comment: I tried `SendKeys.SendWait("%{ADD}%" & ChrW(Convert.ToInt32(i, 16)))`, because I'm working with a var for the char's code. It doesn't work. As the other tries I mentioned, nothing happens.

Comment: @Lars you can try with `Convert.ToInt32(i)` (remove the `, 16`)

Comment: Sorry just **WORKING**. It was just the wrong char code. The `, 16` has to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Put the keys within parentheses to indicate that <kbd>ALT</kbd> should be *held down* while pressing the others.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%({ADD}251)")
```

Comment: @Lars : I just realized that this is the same as your third attempt... I think what you're trying to do is not possible using `SendKeys`. I will see what I can come up with in about an hour.

Comment: @Lars : Okay, that hour lasted longer than expected, sorry about that (something unexpected came up). I'll see if I can mix something up soon, meanwhile I'd try SuperPeanut's solution as that is very easy, if it works.

Comment: Okay so I have tried different variations of the `SendInput` WinAPI function but with no success. Are you sure that your third attempt presses the keys simultaneously? Because it shouldn't. What is this really for?

Comment: I will try this method with parentheses again, you'll hear back soon.

Comment: MSDN article to SendKeys: "To specify that any combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held down while several other keys are pressed, enclose the code for those keys in parentheses. For example, to specify to hold down SHIFT while E and C are pressed, use "+(EC)"."

Comment: @Lars : I know, which is why it should work. They _shouldn't_ be pressed simultaneously. The `SendInput` WinAPI function would be the other way to go, but I have not been able to get it to hold down ALT.